# How to copy static char* to unsigned char* in C?

Tags: c, char, unsigned

I am using a libray function which is expecting the input as unsigned char* and i have a static char array which need to be passed into the library function. Is it better to copy signed char* to unsigned char* variable and pass it to the function or simple cast should do?

```
void test()
{
    static char test[1024];
    libAPI(test);
}

void libAPI(unsigned char* test)
{
    ----------------
}
```

Comment: A simple cast will do.

Comment: `LibAPI((unsigned char *)test);`

Comment: Is it valid to convert signed char* to unsigned char*

Comment: It's a cast. You just tell the compiler "forget its initial type and do as if it was unsigned instead!" (no conversion)

Comment: Why not change your array from `char` to `unsigned char`?

Answer (score 4):

Because the character types are special in C, a pointer to any object type may be converted to a pointer to a character type and used to access the bytes of the object. C 2018 6.3.2.3 7 says:

> … When a pointer to an object is converted to a pointer to a character type, the result points to the lowest addressed byte of the object. Successive increments of the result, up to the size of the object, yield pointers to the remaining bytes of the object.

Thus, you may convert a `char *` to an `unsigned char *` and pass it to the library routine, supposing that the library routine is indeed going to use it to access `unsigned char` and not perform shenanigans with it. The `static` is irrelevant.

Note that if an object was defined with `volatile` or `const`, these qualifiers should be respected.

This is not generally true of other types. If you have a pointer to `int` and a routine expects a pointer to `unsigned int`, the C standard might not define the behavior of the library routine when you pass a converted pointer to it, depending on what is going on inside the library.